# Parsing RSS using retrofit

Tags: android, xml, rss, retrofit, retrofit2

Developing android app and trying to parse news RSS feed but the app keeps failing. I can parse RSS when xml starts with `feed` but when xml looks like this `<rss><channel></channel></rss>`. I can track the problem is in channel class with Item list and if I add required = false the app does not crush. These are my classes to parse RSS.

```
@Root(name = "rss")

public class Feed implements Serializable{

@Element(name = "channel")
private Channel mChannel;

public Channel getmChannel() {
    return mChannel;
}

public Feed() {
}

public Feed(Channel mChannel) {
    this.mChannel = mChannel;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Feed{" +
            "mChannel=" + mChannel +
            '}';
}
```

}
Channel class

```
@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)


public class Channel implements Serializable{

@ElementList(inline = true, name = "item")
public List<Item> items;

public Channel() {
}

public Channel(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Channel{" +
            "items=" + items +
            '}';
}
```

Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            //converter XML
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    FeedGitXivAPI feedGitXiv = retrofit.create(FeedGitXivAPI.class);

    Call<Channel> call = feedGitXiv.getGitXiv();
```

This is the logcat message

```
onFailure: Unable to retrieve RSS: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=true, name=item, required=true, type=void) on field 'items' public java.util.List com.example.anton.techy.AiMl.Channel.items for class com.example.anton.techy.AiMl.Channel at line -1
```

Comment: Problem fixed, forgot to add strict = false in Feed class